# Importing with Parameters in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

This is just something short I have not been able to find out while I've been re-writing my app to be ES6-ready:

Say I had a function with a paramater `router` exported from a model `'./app/routes/api'` and I wanted to import it in my main app.js with the syntax `import 'a' from b`, but pass the `router` Paramater (that has been pre-defined as `let router = express.Router();` with it, so that it would be `var apiRoutes = require('./app/routes/api')(router);` in CommonJS require statements. How could you do that in ES6?

Comment: No way to get the same behavior with the `import` syntax. The `require` version will work regardless.

Comment: Writing the function with a default argument is an approach to consider. But it certainly wouldn't be equivalent to what you're describing and might not be practical depending on the function.